# How do I apply styles with styled-components to a component that is wrapped in material UI grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have this Footer component where a Grid element of material-ui package gets returned with an id to apply scss rules. That now is using an scss stylesheet

**Footer.scss**

```
#footer__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

**Footer.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Typography, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import "components/layout/Footer/Footer.scss";

const Footer = props => {
  const { palette } = props.theme;

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      id="footer__wrapper"
      style={{ backgroundColor: palette.primary.dark }}
    >
      <Grid item>
        <Typography
          variant="h5"
          style={{ color: palette.secondary.contrastText }}
        >
          Footer - Navigational links
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

const styles = {};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Footer);
```

The thing is that now I want to get rid of the scss stylesheet and convert it into a **style-component** but I haven't been able to achieve it. I got rid of the scss file and tried using the styled() method from **styled-components** to define the rules without any success

**Footer.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Typography, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Footer = props => {
  const { palette } = props.theme;

  return (
    <Grid container style={{ backgroundColor: palette.primary.dark }}>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography
          variant="h5"
          style={{ color: palette.secondary.contrastText }}
        >
          Footer - Navigational links
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

const StyledFooter = styled(Footer)`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
`;

const styles = {};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(StyledFooter);
```

After this changes the footer loses all its styling and the rules aren't applied. Any ideas on how to achieve what I want and combine this two together? I tried the point 2) [here](https://medium.com/sipios/use-styled-components-with-material-ui-react-e0759f9a15ce) but it's not working. Thanks!!

Comment: Does it work without using `withStyles`? Might be conflicting those two

Comment: I used the Grid instead of the Footer to build the styled component and it worked